# Is the use of exec for variable assignment pythonic?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, design-patterns, exec

Consider this code:

```
self._t10_test = None
self._t20_test = None
self._t30_test = None

id_lst = ['10', '20', '30']
msg_lst = ['Message for A', 'Message for B', 'Message for C')
```

Is it correct to make use of `exec` in this scenario?

```
for id, msg in zip(id_lst, msg_lst):
    exec((f'self._t{id}_test = {msg}')
```

Or would this be more pythonic?

```
for id, msg in zip(id_lst, msg_lst):
    set_msg(id, msg)


def set_msg(id, msg):
    if id == '10':
        self._t10_test = msg
    elif id == '20':
        self._t20_test = msg
    elif id == '30':
        self._t30_test = msg
```

Comment: Rule of thumb: `exec` is never pythonic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of [`exec()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) is invariably a bad idea. I find generally that if you ever think you need variables within variable names, a better choice is to use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). For your example:

```
self._t_test = {'10': None,
                '20': None,
                '30': None}

id_lst = ['10', '20', '30']
msg_lst = ['Message for A', 'Message for B', 'Message for C']


for i, msg in zip(id_lst, msg_lst):
    self._t_test[i] = msg
```

Which gives us:

```
>>> self._t_test
{'10': 'Message for A', '20': 'Message for B', '30': 'Message for C'}
>>> self._t_test['10']
'Message for A'
```

You could even use a dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> self._t_test = {k: v for k, v in zip(id_lst, msg_lst)}
>>> self._t_test
{'10': 'Message for A', '20': 'Message for B', '30': 'Message for C'}
```

Comment: Another option is:  `self._t_test = dict(zip(id_lst, msg_lst))`